# Efficient way to read a property file in java

Tags: java, properties, file-read

I want to read a property file which has only the values (i.e. Not as a key value pair). 
My property file will contain only the list of strings (more than 1000 words).

I am just using the `IOUtils` to read the file as below:

```
InputStream inputStream = ReadProperty.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(FILE_NAME);
keywords = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
```

What would be the efficient way to maintain the property file.

1. Maintaining the words as comma separated

EG:

```
Good,Bad,Better,Best,Could,Would
```

2. Maintaining the words in each line

EG:

```
Good
Bad
Better
Best
Could
Would
```

I feel the second option is readable but i want to understand that is there any performance issue occurs due to new line character (`\n`)

Comment: There will be (almost) no performace issue here... the `,` character takes the same amount of bytes as the `\n` newline character (only thing could be that under windows the newline symbol is `\r\n`) Plus you have another advantage: with a Reader you can use readline to read in the single properties

Comment: If you don't have key/value pairs, it isn't a properties file... it's best not to try to use the same phrase to mean multiple things. I agree with ParkerHalo that this sounds unlikely to be significant in terms of performance.

Comment: A file with 1000 words should take less than a milli-second either way. Are you sure that performance is an issue for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you go with the newline representation you could use this easy way to read the lines:

```
ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("false"))) {
    String value;
    while ((value = br.readLine()) != null) {
        values.add(value);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

Regarding performance:

The character `','` and the character `'\n'` do use the same space on disc, unless you write the lines with a file-writer which is aware of the platform you're working on (it'll write `"\r\n"` on windows systems). Performance won't be influenced very much (especially if you only have about 1000 entrys)

Comment: You don't need to re-invent the wheel: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29 (Java7+) or https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path- (Java8 only)

Comment: @Tom you're completely right about that, but I think it's not bad to know how to read the file line-wise yourself ;)